# Touched ground of a 2 wire soldering iron

Tags: voltage, soldering

First off, I'd like to say that this is a bit of a stupid mistake. I'm new to electronics and soldering, and I have a 110 V 60W soldering iron. It has an external ground wire where I can connect to a ground, however when I grabbed it, I accidentally had it touch my skin near my wrist and it began feeling cold, however I wasn't sure if that was a shock. Is it something I should be worrying about, as I feel perfectly fine now? Thank you.

Comment: You'll be fine. Metal feels cold. If in doubt consult a doctor, not the internet.

Comment: The wire could be just cold :) But even if you were shocked and you don't feel any consequences, don't worry. Electrical shocks don't usually produce hidden or delayed injures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That ground wire should be connected to the dirt via the outlet. There is no danger from touching a grounded conductor unless you are energized. You would know if you received a shock. It is startling and painful. Feeling coldness indicates that you were just feeling a piece of harmless metal.

Even if it was a shock, there is no hazard once energy has been removed, unless you suffer from a heart condition or have implanted medical devices.